# Shorten jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to shorten the following jQuery code into one single block?  At the moment, the current code is 2 blocks, but it is practically identical.  I tried adding `.break-row` to the first selector but this then results in the incorrect value of `k`.

```
$(div).find('.overtime-row').each(function(k, subRow)
{
    // get all fields
    $(subRow).find('input, select').each(function(l, subElement)
    {
        var inputName = $(subElement).attr('data-name');
        var parts = inputName.split(':');

        $(subElement).attr('name', 'row[' + i + '][' + parts[0] + '][' + k + '][' + parts[1] + ']');
    });
});

$(div).find('.break-row').each(function(k, subRow)
{
    // get all fields
    $(subRow).find('input, select').each(function(l, subElement)
    {
        var inputName = $(subElement).attr('data-name');
        var parts = inputName.split(':');

        $(subElement).attr('name', 'row[' + i + '][' + parts[0] + '][' + k + '][' + parts[1] + ']');
    });
});
```

Can anyone advise if this is possible? I'm just looking to keep clean code.

Comment: The problem with this question is two-fold: 1) It's not written well enough so that someone else with a similar question would be able to find this one, 2) No one ever searches google for "shorten JQuery Code" (and if they did; should they find this question every time?) 3) This should be asked on Code-Review if you don't have an actual problem with the code.

Comment: Put the body in a named function, and call that function in two `.each()` loops.

Comment: Where do you get the `i` for `row[' + i + ']` ?

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Put the repeated code in a named function so you can call it from both loops.

```
function addNameAttr(i, subElement) {
    var inputName = $(subElement).attr('data-name');
    var parts = inputName.split(':');

    $(subElement).attr('name', 'row[' + i + '][' + parts[0] + '][' + k + '][' + parts[1] + ']');
}
$(div).find(".overtime-row").each(addNameAttr);
$(div).find(".break-row").each(addNameAttr);
```